# How to tell if a property of an EntityObject is a primary key or foreign key?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, primary-key

Suppose that I have a class generated by Entity Framework called `Student`.

`Student` has the following properties:

```
Id int,
Name, string
Age, int
TeacherId int
```

Suppose further that `Id` refers to the primary key in SQL that identifies what student a `Student` object refers to and `TeacherId` is a foreign key that tells who the student's teacher is.

Suppose I want to write a function which takes *any* `EntityObject` (such as this one) as a parameter and returns information about which properties are primary keys and foreign keys.

How can I do this?

If this is not appropriate, then how can Entity Framework tell me which properties are primary and foreign keys?

For now, let's not take into consideration composite key fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the code that is autogenerated, I can see that primitive properties in the generated class have several attributes, and among these is an `EdmScalarPropertyAttribute` which has a boolean `EntityKeyProperty` which seems to indicate whether or not the property is a key.

How to read the values of the attributes is described in an article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct.aspx

I'll bet that I can find a consistent pattern for how foreign keys are handled as well!

Answer (score 0):

I have little support section in Repository for such questions.
**See the GetEntityKeyFields method below**
I dont have check routine already written FK, but if you check the entityField details, it will be there as well.

```
    public DbEntityEntry<T> Entry(T entity) { return Context.Entry(entity); }
    public DbSet<T> EntityDbSet() { return Context.Set<T>(); } // cant be in core interface since it is EF types
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext { get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this.Context).ObjectContext; } }
    // cant be in core interface since it is EF types
    public BosBaseDbContext Context { get; protected set; }

    public EntityState GetEntityState(T entity) { return Context.Entry(entity).State; }
    public  ObjectSet<T> GetObjectSet() { return ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>(); }

    public string[] GetEntityFields() { return GetObjectSet().EntitySet.ElementType.Properties.Select(e => e.Name).ToArray(); }
    public string[] GetEntityKeyFields() { return GetObjectSet().EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray(); }

    public EntityKey GetEntityKey(T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(GetObjectSet().EntitySet.Name, entity);
    }
```